# How to merge two lists of different types into one list of new type that contains both types?

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I want to combine/merge/join/whatever a list of `enum`s, so that each item in the unified list will have two fields - the name of the `enum` item (`string Name`), and its value (`TokensEnum Token`):

```
var tokens = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TokensEnum));
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (TokensEnum));

var combined = InTheDarknessBindThem(tokens,names);

foreach(var c in combined)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
        "Token \"{0}\" value is {1}", c.Name, (int)c.Token));
```

How to write the body of the following method (preferably LINQ-wise)?

```
InTheDarknessBindThem(IEnumerable<TokensEnum> tokens, IEnumerable<string> names) {
    /*
        ...
    */
}
```

Comment: +1 for creative method names

Comment: Why would you just not call `ToString()` on each value to get the name? There's no need to get the names and values separately.

Comment: @JonSkeet, that's obvious, but not the point. It's just a simple demonstration for what I want to achieve: the goal is to have a `Dictionary<string,TokensEnum>` for some kind of parser, and each `enum` can be decorated with attributes (but doesn't have to..)

Comment: @Tal: So please give a more representative example. It's not clear how a dictionary fits in here, or what you'd actually have...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both lists are in order, you can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
tokens.Cast<TokensEnum>().Zip(names, (t, n) => Tuple.Create(t, n));
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<TokensEnum, string>>`.

But as [*Jon Skeet* suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616527/how-to-merge-two-lists-of-different-types-into-one-list-of-new-type-that-contain/20616565#comment30853437_20616527), in this case, it would probably be easier to do something like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(TokensEnum))
    .Cast<TokensEnum>()
    .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t, t.ToString()));
```

This will return the same result as above, but it will do it in a single step.

Since you mentioned in your comments that you'd like to have a `Dictionary<string, TokensEnum>`, you can use something like this to construct it:

```
Dictionary<string, TokensEnum> myDictionary = 
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(TokensEnum))
        .Cast<TokensEnum>()
        .ToDictionary(t => t.ToString());
```

Comment: Your first answer is what I was looking for! Thanks! The rest are obvious, but I must do some processing before adding them to the dictionary, **if at all**: attribute-fetching (and acting accordingly) and Regexp manipulations, to name a few..

Comment: @Tal You could *probably* do all (or most) of that in a single linq query as well. But glad I could help.

Comment: Indeed, I can probably do it in a single LINQ query (and as yourself, I'm not 100% sure about it..), but as you most likely already know, in terms of readability it's many times better not to. In this case, there's a lot of code inside the `foreach` that comes afterwards (and that's another reason why I didn't provide the whole code)

Answer (score 1):

Why not a dictionary?

```
var dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof (TokensEnum))
               .Cast<TokensEnum>()
               .ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.ToString());
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}, Name: {1}",kvp.Key,kvp.Value);
}
```

The printout is a bit moot since ToString() is called on value.

I think using enum as key in a dictionary cases boxing.